# Why is the menubar method not working in following code?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code which doesn't work

```
import tkinter as tk


class english_to_ubbidubbi:

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.title("Ubbi Dubbi")

        menubar=tk.Menu(self.master)
        file = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label ='Exit', menu = file)
        file.add_separator()
        file.add_command(label ='Exit', command = self.master.destroy)

        self.frame1=tk.Frame(self.master)
        tk.Label(self.frame1,text='Hello There').grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.frame1.grid(row=1,column=0)

win=tk.Tk()
app=english_to_ubbidubbi(win)
win.mainloop()
```

Above produces a widget without menu bar, whereas the code below works fine

```
import tkinter  as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Ubbi Dubbi')


menubar = tk.Menu(root)

file = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='File', menu = file)

file.add_separator()
file.add_command(label ='Exit', command = root.destroy)

root.config(menu = menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

What am I doing wrong here

....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 3):

You didn't use `.config(menu=menubar)` in the first example, use:

```
class english_to_ubbidubbi:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Ubbi Dubbi")

        menubar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        file = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Exit', menu=file)
        file.add_separator()
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.master.destroy)

        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.master)
        tk.Label(self.frame1, text='Hello There').grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.frame1.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Or:

```
class english_to_ubbidubbi:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Ubbi Dubbi")

        menubar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        file = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Exit', menu=file)
        file.add_separator()
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.master.destroy)

        win.config(menu=menubar)

        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.master)
        tk.Label(self.frame1, text='Hello There').grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.frame1.grid(row=1, column=0)
```